# ElementName binding doesn't work for IsMouseOver in ControlTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a control template and I want to trigger some actions only if mouse is over a certain part of it.  Here is the core of my template (simplified for demonstration):

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type graphicElements:MyTabItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot">
         <Grid x:Name="templateChild" />
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, ElementName=templateChild}" Value="True">
              <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="templateRoot" Value="Red" />
         </DataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

When I put ElementName as templateRoot it works and turns red.  When I put it as templateChild it doesn't work... Why not?

Comment: You need to put the _not simplified version_ code in order to determine your actual problem. Empty grid will not raise IsMouseOver event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the simplified version of your code the binding to the templateRoot grid also won't work. The problem is, that WPF needs to perform [Hit Tests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/hit-testing-in-the-visual-layer) on the elements to raise certain events or to update the IsMouseOver property. Since you don't have a background brush set for the grids, they will never receive mouse inputs, hence your trigger will never execute. Try this:

```
<Grid x:Name="templateRoot">
    <Grid x:Name="templateChild" Background="Transparent"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: <Insert expletives here>.  Thanks, that's what kind of day it's been...  Indeed I did not have the background set, thank you.